# Append a component dynamically

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, components

I try to append a component dynamically, here it's Boards that i try to add to MainComponent.
The function addChild work and the list *boards* is filling up when the loop *for* is running, but nothing else happen, nothing is displayed on the screen

````
const MainComponent = props => (
    <div className={props.className}>
        <p>
            <a href="#" onClick={props.addChild}>Add Another Child Component</a>
        </p>
        {props.boards}
    </div>
);

class MainPage extends React.Component {

    state = {
        numChildren: 0
    }

    onAddChild = () => {
        this.setState({
            numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1
        });
    }

    render () {

        const boards = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
            var _id = "board-" + i;
            console.log
            boards.push(<Board id={_id} className="board" />);
        };

        return (
            <div className="test">
                <Title/>
                <MainComponent addChild={this.onAddChild} className="flexbox">
                    {boards}
                </MainComponent>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MainPage```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to add key for each `ChildComponent`

```
const boards = [];

for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
    var _id = "board-" + i;
    console.log
    boards.push(<Board id={_id} key={_id} className="board" />);
};
```

because react depends on the key for rendering the component that is rendered inside loops

so react considers that all child that you are rendering is one component unless you give them a different key